# Read image OCR python loop through result

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to read an imgae with the extension tiff and I could read text (not exact text) but there is a number of length 12 which I need to extract
Here's the code till now

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale, Gaussian Blur, Otsu's Threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.tiff')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph Open To Remove Noise And Invert Image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening

# Perform Text Extraction
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

Here's the result of the code

```
| * 4 ” 12 ;
PARISH ve ARUN R S pa
RE ORI Sse GO
STATE OF KUWAIT GiviL iD GARD
‘- CivilIDNo 277112702404 gail east
f q . . ow!
|
| : Name — - Torr
|  passportNo A16617816 ity i! 8
e >t! Nationality EGY St A oll
Sex M 93 ja
Me. Pit Date 27/11/1977 sat
e . ExpiryDate 18/03/2021 sleoy! ay
```

What I need is to loop through the lines and when a number of 12 digits is found, then exit the the loop and extract the number.

Here's the sample tiff file

[image]

The desired number here is `277112702404`

** I have another image but this one doesn't return any result and throws an

```
error like that
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

How can I change the code so as to be able to get the text from such images too?
[image]

Comment: is the image always this clean ? AKA in such a perfect cut? As you could just cut even further first to the zone to are interested and then do ocr there.

Comment: So your question is to find a 12-digit number in a given string?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to implement the code on the link but I couldn't.

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: I am just a beginner at python and I am not still accustomed to it.

Comment: I could do that by these two lines `import re
re.findall("(\d{12})\D", data)`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have updated the post as I encountered a problem with a specific image. Can you help me please?